# Evaluate $\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{4}+...+\binom{n}{2k}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

What is the closed formula for finding

> $$
> \sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{n}{2i}=?\quad ,k\leq \lfloor{n/2}\rfloor
> $$

I need summation only up to some intermediate  $k$ where $k\leq \lfloor{n/2}\rfloor$ .

SAY I need a closed formula to calculate $\binom{8}{0}+ \binom{8}{2}+\binom{8}{4} +\binom{8}{6}$

HERE $n=8$ and $k=6$

Comment: What is `Ncx` ?

Comment: NcR,N CHOOSE R.

Comment: Hint: think about (1+x)^n, and consult [this section](http://dlmf.nist.gov/1.2)  in DLMF.

Comment: @SMA.D EXACTLY THIS IS MY QUESTION AND PEOPLE EDITED IT WRONG

Comment: @SMA.D CAN YOU JUST EDIT THE QUESTION ? what u wrote is my question

Comment: “Up to some intermediate $k$ where $k$” is what?

Comment: here k<=Nlook at the comment of @SMA.D .THIS IS WHAT MY QUESTION IS

Comment: @SMA.D k<=n /2and not k<=n/4 as you edited it now

Comment: In your example k should be 2 then $2i\in\{0,2,4\}$ and $\sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{N}{2i}= \binom{8}{0}+ \binom{8}{2}+\binom{8}{4}$

Comment: the example can be simply removed from question

Comment: In the edited example k should be 3 not 6.

Comment: This is just the partial sum of $C(n-1,i)$ up to $i=2k$.  There won't be anything that you would likely call a closed form, but there are asymptotics depending on how large $k$ is relative to $n$ (for instance, if $k \approx \alpha n$ for some fixed $0<\alpha<\tfrac12$ or if $k \approx \sqrt{n}$).  Just search around for partial sum of binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 7):

We show a closed formula for $k=\lfloor n/2\rfloor$. For the general case, it is possible to give some asymptotic bounds. See here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n

We have that: 
$$0=(1-1)^n=\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}(-1)^i=\sum_{i \text{ even}}\binom{n}{i}-\sum_{i \text{ odd}}\binom{n}{i},$$
and
$$2^n=(1+1)^n=\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}=\sum_{i \text{ even}}\binom{n}{i}+\sum_{i \text{ odd}}\binom{n}{i}.$$
Therefore for $n\geq 1$,
$$\sum_{i \text{ even}}\binom{n}{i}=\sum_{i \text{ odd}}\binom{n}{i}=2^{n-1}.$$

Comment: your answer is just for $k=\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor$ the question wants $k\leq\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor$.

Comment: @SMA.D Thank you for pointing out. I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 5):

By the binomial theorem,

$$
0=(1-1)^n=\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}(-1)^i=\sum_{i \equiv 0 \pmod 2 }\binom{n}{i}-\sum_{i \equiv 1 \pmod 2}\binom{n}{i}.
$$

$$
2^n=(1+1)^n=\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}1^{i}=\sum_{i \equiv 0 \pmod 2 }\binom{n}{i}+\sum_{i \equiv 1 \pmod 2}\binom{n}{i}.
$$

Thus $$\sum_{i \equiv 0 \pmod 2 }\binom{n}{i}=2^{n-1}$$

Comment: the question has been edited properly