# Calculating $\sum_{k=0}^{13} \binom{26}{2k}\frac{(2k)!}{k!2^k}$

Tags: combinatorics

it may be an odd request but I'm trying to calculate a certain number and atm I lack any advance software like MATLAB or Maple. I also failed to find any good calculator online that would be able to calculate it. I want to use it for further calculations regarding permutations.

Can anyone calculate it for me?

$\sum_{k=0}^{13} \binom{26}{2k}\frac{(2k)!}{k!2^k}$

Thanks!

Comment: You could also use a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get $532 \ 985 \ 208 \ 200 \ 576$ using [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%5Cbinom%7B26%7D%7B2k%7D%5Cfrac%7B%282k%29%21%7D%7Bk%212%5Ek%7D%20from%20k%3D0%20to%2013).  This number is approximately $5.33 \times 10^{14}$.

For your particular question, it helps a lot to note that $\sum_{\text{i even}} {n \choose i} = 2^{n-1}$ ([this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1896994/evaluate-binomn0-binomn2-binomn4-binomn2k)). In your case then, you have $\sum_{k=0}^{13} {26 \choose {2k}} = 2^{25}$. Most modern calculators (not graphing calculators) have a button for the factorial, so the rest can be computed by calculator.

Comment: Thanks! Could you also do $26! \sum_{i=0}^{26}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$ please?

Comment: You can just go to Wolfram Alpha and type it yourself. For the summation, you have to type the limits of the summation out like the end, something like: (sum (-1)^i/i! from i=0 to 26).

Comment: For the summation, it might also be help to note that it very nearly equals $\frac{1}{e}$.